# Boolean variables not changing to true

Tags: java, events, graphics, boolean, keylistener

I'm writing a class to move a circle around the screen, but the main problem is that the boolean variables are not changing to true, despite my attempts at making them change to true. I don't know what I'm doing wrong. Please help. Thanks.

```
public class Restart extends Panel implements KeyListener {

    static final int left = 37;
    static final int right = 39;
    static final int down = 40;
    static final int up = 38;

    static boolean leftPress = false;
    static boolean rightPress = false;
    static boolean upPress = false;
    static boolean downPress = false;

    static int x1 = 0;
    static int y1 = 0;

    Restart(int width, int length, int minusBy) {
        super(width, length, minusBy);
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) throws InterruptedException {
        Restart panel = new Restart(500, 500, 9);
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Fishy");
        frame.add(panel);
        Frame.showFrame(frame);

        while (true) {

            if (upPress) {
                y1--;
            }
            if (downPress) {
                y1++;
            }
            if (leftPress) {
                x1--;
            }
            if (rightPress) {
                x1++;
            }

            Thread.sleep(1);
            frame.repaint();
        }
    }

    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);

        g.fillOval(x1, y1, 50, 50);
    }

    @Override
    public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {

        if (up == e.getKeyCode()) {
            upPress = true;
        }
        if (down == e.getKeyCode()) {
            downPress = true;
        }
        if (left == e.getKeyCode()) {
            leftPress = true;
        }
        if (right == e.getKeyCode()) {
            rightPress = true;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {

        if (up == e.getKeyCode()) {
            upPress = false;
        }
        if (down == e.getKeyCode()) {
            downPress = false;
        }
        if (left == e.getKeyCode()) {
            leftPress = false;
        }
        if (right == e.getKeyCode()) {
            rightPress = false;
        }
    }

    /* NOT USING */
    @Override
    public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) {
    }
}
```

Comment: Use key bindings over `KeyListener` in order to overcome all the related issues with `KeyListener`.  See [How to Use Key Bindings](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/keybinding.html)

Comment: Oh, and unless you're using a `BufferStrategy`, I'd also recommend using the Swing library over the AWT library...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You never add the keylistener to any component. So you won't get any input. Add restart as keylistener to some `Component` (`JPanel` and some others might need to be made focusable using `setFocusable(true)`) by calling `someComponent.addKeyListener(this)`. I'd recommend you add the listener to the `Restart` instance itself.

Comment: Oh that. thanks. btw, i thought that the keylistener sleeps for exactly 33 milliseconds when you hold it once, but class isn't sleeping for 33 millseconds? You know why?

Comment: what exactly do you mean by "when you hold it once"?

Comment: @wolfpupxd It's a common delay generated by the OS which delays the time between the first key press and repeated key presses. Generally, you should raise a flag indicating which key is currently pressed and use some kind of update loop to process the logic based on which keys are currently flagged

Comment: @MadProgrammer yeah that's the thing though. I'm expecting the 33 milliseconds delay, but it's not delaying at all in my class. the circles move RIGHT AWAY after I press the keys. It doesn't delay for 33 millseconds at all. I can tell because I had an old class that did delay for 33 millseconds. But my new class isn't delaying at all. I'm glad it's not delaying, but I'm just wondering why.

Comment: @wolfpupxd Sorry, now that I've read your code through, it's because you're using a loop to process the key flags, so they don't care about the time between the key press events